Stream logs with Java Spring Boot + PHP + JS
I am working on a Hackathon idea where I have implemented some REST endpoints in the Java Spring Boot application to run some shell scripts and stream the shell outputs with Server side Event (SSE). One example is:
    @GetMapping(value = "/get-sandbox-details", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public SseEmitter getSandboxDetails(@RequestParam String name) {
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                CommandResponse commandResponse = scriptExecutionService.executeCommand("path/to/script " + name);
                emitter.send(commandResponse.getOutput());
                emitter.complete();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                emitter.completeWithError(e);
            }
        }).start();

        return emitter;
    }

There are multiple action buttons in UI that call the PHP script to make calls to these REST endpoints to execute the shell commands. The request route through Browser/JS -> call to PHP -> curl call to java application - http://localhost:8090/some-rest-endpoint?name=xyz.
The reason I had to route the request through PHP is that server ports are blocked, so direct access to these REST endpoints through Browser/JS is not possible.
The regular REST endpoints (not streaming shell outputs) work perfectly fine with the above approach. But how can I stream and display the script outputs in real-time with the above approach?
One way would be long polling to the REST endpoint in PHP and the JS? Although not sure how to go ahead and implement this approach
Would appreciate any directions and sample code to work with. Thank you!
